# Ancient prophecies involving alcohol?

Tags: folklore, origins, mythohistory

**Are there any ancient prophecies involving alcohol?**

I asked this question on Beer, Wine & Spirits SE some two years ago and have not received an answer: [**Prophecies involving alcohol?**](https://alcohol.stackexchange.com/questions/7809/prophecies-involving-alcohol)

When we read the Life of Nostradamus, we come across a rather strange little prophecy. Put in a short manner, it states that whoever drank from the skull of Nostradamus would inherit his incredible powers.

The introductory sequence had a subtitle 'France 1791' and showed a number of soldiers digging up a grave.

The narrator spoke;

> "There was a legend that whoever drank from the skull of Nostradamus would inherit his incredible powers. But for 200 years his grave had remained undisturbed because the legend also said that whoever did so, would immediately die. One night, at the height of the French Revolution, three drunken soldiers set out to test the legend.
>
> It was not the skeleton that suddenly sobered the soldiers, but the plaque around its neck, with the date: May 1791, which could only have been placed there at the time of burial in 1566, Nostradamus had predicted, 200 years before, the exact date when his body would be dug up."
>
> Anyway one of the soldiers poured some wine into the skull and took a swig. As he did so, a shot rang out, and he dropped, dead as well as drunk. - [**Nostradamus: His Imagined Life.**](http://users.adam.com.au/bstett/PaNostradamus12.htm)

Thus my question: **Does anyone know of any ancient prophecies (legends, mythologies or folklore) of future events that involve the consumption of drinking alcohol in one form or another?**

Comment: Wherever the catholic sun doth shine, there's always laughter and good red wine.

Comment: @Lucian That is one of my favourite lines: **“Wherever the Catholic sun doth shine,
There’s always laughter and good red wine.
At least I’ve always found it so.
Benedicamus Domino!”** - Hilaire Belloc.